# Footfullcite not showing when used within a wrapfigure

Tags: biblatex, citing, wrapfigure

I'm using the `wrapfig` package for a figure that wraps itself around the text and `biblatex` for all my citing with these parameters:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=numeric,
        sorting=none,
        sortlocale=de_DE,
]{biblatex}
```

Now when I want to place the picture I use this code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{picture}
\footfullcite{somedude}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Using this code, the picture places where I want and the little 1 indicating that I want to cite this is at the bottom right corner. The problem is that in the footnotes the 1 doesn't appear. It just shows the over foot citations.
I get no error or anything to debug this.
(citation key and picture path is also right)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Footnotes in floats are never easy. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41626/35864 help? More generally there is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/35864. If not it would be appreciated if you could show us an MWE so we have something to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can't use `\footnote{lorem ipsum}` from within a float, see [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/35864). Instead you issue `\footnotemark` within the float and `\footnotetext{lorem ipsum}` after the figure.

In this case `biblatex` issues the `\footnote` command for you, so you need a way to make it use `\footnotetext` instead. In fact a version of `\footcite` that uses `\footnotetext` already exists: `\footcitetext`. We just make our own version of `\footfullcite` that uses `\footnotetext` and call it `\footfullcitetext`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\footnotemark
\end{wrapfigure}\footfullcitetext{sigfridsson}
\lipsum[2-3]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]